cypress-tags and cypress run both failing to executed only tagged test cases in cypress-cucumber framework
I tried cypress-tags and cypress run commands to execute tagged test cases but both are failing. can someone guide for solution?
dependancy versions:
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^21.0.3",
"@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.3",
"cypress": "^13.16.0",
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
"cypress-on-fix": "^1.0.3",
"cypress-xray-plugin": "^7.4.1"
I have included filterspec and omitfilter in package.json:
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"filterSpecs": true,
"omitFiltered": true,
"nonGlobalStepdefinitions": false,
"stepDefinitions": [
"cypress/e2e/Stepdefinitions/**/*.{js,ts}"
],
I have integrated cypress-xray plugin as well to upload execution results to Jira cloud.
I have 2 features files:
Login.feature:
Feature: Cucumber test set
@smoke
@TEST_CYP-4 @TESTSET_CYP-9
Scenario: cucumber trial test case
    Given user is on example website
    And user passes valid credentials
    Then user login is successful

@smoke  
@TEST_CYP-10 @TESTSET_CYP-9
Scenario: cucumber test case 2
    Given user is on example website
    And user passes valid credentials
    Then user login is successful
    
@TEST_CYP-11 @TESTSET_CYP-9
Scenario: cucumber test case 3
    Given user is on example website
    And user passes valid credentials
    Then user login is successful

Addcustomer.feature:
Feature: Cucumber test set 2
@TEST_CYP-16 @TESTSET_CYP-15
Scenario: cucumber test case 1 - test set 2
    Given user is on example website
    And user passes valid credentials
    Then user login is successful
    
@TEST_CYP-17 @TESTSET_CYP-15
Scenario: cucumber test case 2 - test set 2
    Given user is on example website
    And user passes valid credentials
    Then user login is successful

command using for execution:
npx cypress run --record --key  --browser chrome --spec cypress/e2e/features/regression --env JIRA_USERNAME=<jira_username>,JIRA_API_TOKEN=<jira_apitoken>,XRAY_CLIENT_ID=<xray_clientid>,XRAY_CLIENT_SECRET=<xray_clientsecret> tags="@smoke"
instead of running only 2 scenarios mentioned with @smoke tag, cypress executes all the scenarios from both feature files.

The tag feature works ok for me - can you provide a reproducible example?

I am working with above code only to verify the tag execution. but in my case, the mentioned command running all the test scenarios of the feature

is there any change in the command needed @Karen.Schlossberg

Yes, start from the simplest example that works, using only one tag and add things in until it breaks - that's what is erroring. You may need to get a tester to help you conduct the experiment, but TBH it's not hard.

is the same command you used to execute which I have mentioned above?

finally got this working!! Thanks

One thing that's wrong is you have
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^21.0.3", 
...
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",

Get rid of the old defunct v4.3.2 as it probably causes problems all over the place. Also make sure it's gone from cypress.config.js.
